# PyDev in Eclipse - packages displayed as regular folders

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, package-explorer

Usually this is cause by the **init**.py missing in the package. But I do have all my **init**.py into place. In the PyDev package explorer, packages are displayed as yellow rectangles, just like regular folders, rather than with the package icon. Why is this? I've tried clean all, build all, doesn't help.

Comment: Just to clarify, it should be `__init__.py`

Comment: Sure. I think __ was interpretted as bold font.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Are you under the `PyDev` perspective? `Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Other > PyDev`

Comment: Yes. I also noticed that Ctrl+Click doesn't work. Really confused, I don't know what changed, worked until few hours ago.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the indexer, or PYTHONPATH. Try `Project -> Properties -> PyDev -PYTHONPATH,  "add source folder"`

Comment: That worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with the indexer, or PYTHONPATH. Try `Project -> Properties -> PyDev -PYTHONPATH, "add source folder"`